Force.com Checkmarx Scan Job Cancelled Due to Line of Code Limit
I am currently using a Developer Edition Salesforce org and attempting to run a Force.com Checkmarx scan. However, every time I schedule a scan, the job is cancelled with the following message:
"The scan just requested contains 12210 lines of code, which would exceed the 12 month limit, therefore your job has been cancelled."


Salesforce Edition: Developer Edition
Tool Used: Force.com CheckmarxScan (Force.com CheckMarx)

Due to organizational policies, I am not able to create a partner org for my development purpose.
And I am aware that spinning up a new developer org is an option, but I am seeking alternative solutions.
I am looking for alternative approaches or solutions to run the Force.com Checkmarx scan on my Developer Edition org without exceeding the line of code limit and without violating the constraints mentioned above.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Have you checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-code-analyzer/guide/pmd-engine.html

Yes, I am already running that PMD source code Analyzer over my source code. we actually run both . But in my opinion, over that PMD , checkMarx is great to identify the security issues like CRUD , cross-site scriptiongs and FLS ....etc.

Checkmarx results are very limited and I think PMD does just as good a job without the limits.

ofcourse , but even to publish our App to AppExchange , these checkMarx scan reports are needed right. for that we have to run the scan. My issue is that only, not able to run a scan ......

The org you use doesn't really matter since a partner scan is done using the partner security portal, and this scan does not limit the lines of code like the non-partner version does. You need to create the package version and select that for scanning (not an org).

Exactly ..... but that process is only possible for partner edition versions only, not for developer(free) edition org's versions... Mine org is free developer edition, so that it has the limit for lines of code to scan, that was exceeded now.... My only concern now is , is there any alternative approach to scan the code rather than PMD and spinnin up a new org?  Could you please go through the question once....

I just added/lined by developer org to the partner community , followed this article
Connect your devHub to partner console
